# BIM360 External reference between linked IFC file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm following this example:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim360-docs-setting-external-references-between-files-upload-linked-files

And this input:
[Autodesk Forge - Linking items one to another on BIM 360 docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699771/autodesk-forge-linking-items-one-to-another-on-bim-360-docs)

To restore the links in a host RVT file, for RVT links this works fine.
So far i'm unable to do the same for a linked IFC file.
I tried the *.IFC link as also the *.ifc.rvt file.
Is this possible? any pointers?

Comment: AFAIK, it supports Revit files only, but I'm double-checking with our engineering team for the possibility. Will get back A.S.A.P.

Comment: I hate to disappoint you, but I got the confirmation that we don't support linking IFC files at present. However, we are curious about your use cases and want to know why you want to translate IFC files into one SVF. If it cannot be posted publicly, please contact `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com` instead. **Note. Please remove any confidential information and personal from anything you want to share with us before sending it out.**

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
The use case is simply because we can link IFC in a Revit file. 
For example we link a Steel detail IFC model in a Revit file and use this IFC elements in 3Dviews and sheet views. We expect to see the same elements when looking at the SVF file in Forge. 
At the moment the "workarround" is to convert the IFC to RVT file and link that in the parent Revit file. I was hoping for another solution.

Comment: Ok, thank you for sharing the details, but the IFC translation doesn't go through Revit. Forge uses Navisworks translation pipeline with its IFC loaders to convert IFC files to SVF. So, it could not be the same thing as the Revit desktop.

Comment: However, there could be two possible alternative ways. One is [BIM360 Model Coordination](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/learn-explore/caas/screencast/Main/Details/2f3bd629-e3d7-4934-8140-1b211fd5393a.html), and another is [BIM360 Design Collaboration](https://blogs.autodesk.com/bim360-release-notes/2019/12/05/bim-360-design-collaboration-update-december-9-2019/). They supports IFC recently.

Comment: I will look into these alternatives.
Maybe of topic but [Model Derivative IFC pipeline call to change](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change) it seems to me as of "phase 2" the default pipeline is Revit: 
_"Phase 2: In a few month, the Model Derivative API we will switch the default pipeline to Revit instead."_

Comment: No, it's not Revit actually. The modern (Revit based) translation pipeline is Navisworks translation pipeline with Revit IFC loader. The legacy one is the Navisworks translation pipeline with the legacy IFC loader. You can see a similar thing in the Naviswroks desktop: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/navisworks-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Navisworks-opens-ifc-file-too-slow.html

Comment: And we are still on Phase 1 currently. Model Derivative API uses legacy translation pipeline by default, but BIM360 Docs uses modern translation pipeline by default.